# How to avoid this kind of notation " | undefinded " in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

It's not essential, but I'm asking out of curiosity. In Object type we can declare optional property by using ?: operator, but is there a similar shorthand when I want to declare the function return type?

```
type Type = string | number;

const foo = (): Type | undefined => {
 
  ...

  return;
};
```

Comment: Why do this at all? "Functions should to one thing and do it well" - right? So if there are multiple return types the function is doing many things. The potential end result will be many bugs. Produce something other than a hypothetical so we can chew on something juicy.

Comment: @RandyCasburn you really can't think of a case where a function might want to return `undefined`??

Comment: @jasperuss: no, there is no shorthand for that.

Comment: @NicholasTower - Sure I can. The real question to ask is _should I_?

Comment: Should you think of one? I mean, that's up to you. I won't force you to think if you don't want to. Should you write functions that sometimes return undefined? Yes, when the need arises. For example, the `find` function on arrays.

Comment: @NicholasTower - see a concrete, non-hypothetical example. Works for me. But hypothetical questions with no stated goal or outcome (like this one) cannot be answered directly with a reasonable answer like your comment.

Comment: @jasperuss, if one of the answers answers your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up: `?` (optional property) and `| undefined` are slightly different.
`foo?: number` means that the property `foo` may not exist at all on instances of the type. `'foo' in instance` for example, will return false.
`foo: number | undefined`, however, requires that the `foo` is defined on the instance, even if its *value* is `undefined`.

**There is no shorthand for this (that I know of or can find)**, but to avoid writing the union each time, and to improve the semantics, **you can create a type to represent it**. You can also make specific versions of this type, which can be useful, especially for *nested* generic types.
I have seen this pattern used in several real-world projects ([VueUse](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/), for example).

```
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined
type MaybeNumber = Maybe<number>
type MaybeArray<T> = Maybe<T[]>
type ArrayOfMaybe<T> = Maybe<T>[]

// Example use with variables:

let maybe: Maybe<string> = "Hello, world" // or `undefined`
let maybeNumber: MaybeNumber = 42 // or `undefined`
let maybeNumberArray: MaybeArray<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4] // or `undefined`
let arrayOfMaybeStrings: ArrayOfMaybe<string> = ["abc", undefined, "foo"]
```

It's generally simplest to just use the `Maybe` type directly.
The only cases where it's really beneficial to create a new type based on it is if it is widely used and/or more complex (e.g. unions and such).

**Rambling and thoughts**
The semantics of a shorthand like `?:` would actually be nice for function return signatures, as you could semantically differentiate between "this function might return `undefined` as a value, and this is meaningful" (`f(): T | undefined`) and "this function might not return a meaningful value" (`f()?: T`). Of course, the fact that the function returned `undefined` instead of a value of type `T` must mean *something*, but the value `undefined` itself is not the point in that case, it is that no *other* value was returned.

Comment: Nice answer. Well explained.

Answer (score 0):

No returning undefined is an option also. You can return the default value.

```
const foo = (): Type => {
  let result: type = defaultValue;
  ...

  return result || defaultValue;
};
```